# undefined method `update_attributes' in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This update process something different I need update query inside loop, but showing this error:

> undefined method `update_attributes'

This is code:

```
<%= link_to "Accept", apply_path(accept:{:accept => 1}), :method => :put, class: "btn btn-success" %>
```

Controller:

```
def update
  @accept = Applied.where(params[:applied_id])
  params.permit!
  if @accept.update_attributes(params[:applied_id])
    #flash[:notice] = "updated"
    render 'apply'
  else
    render 'apply'
  end
end
```

request parameters:

> {"_method"=>"put",
>  "authenticity_token"=>"Yk26LKrW9ulRVV6p8GWhqTP7coSg96JiAmU4CUYYFugBgTDR2iRZZlyY1SQ7TbA7B2YVmgulgcWTosXvjnPXZw==",
>  "accept"=>{"accept"=>"1"}}

How can I reach solution?

Comment: your question e unclear. What do you want with that AppliedJob? you are finding applied jobs with ids and then updating those ids ? Also you are having link with POST request and update is by default PUT/PATCH.

Comment: I used PUT/PATCH but showing error

Comment: `where` returns a relation, not an instance. You want to use `find` instead.

Comment: also you params doesn't contain `applied_id'

Comment: show more code from `erb` view

Comment: @try you need to pass `applied_id` in params, which is missing

Comment: @RAJ how can I pass `applied_id` in params ?

Comment: Look at the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35081750/1047207

Answer (score 1):

You can call update_attributes for a single model instance (a record) only not for an ActiveRecord::Relation object (it's like an array of records).

Use:

```
@accept = Applied.where({applied_id:params[:applied_id]}).first
```

or

```
@accept = Applied.find(params[:applied_id])
```

**Be aware**, find looks for your applied_id in the id field of your model table, if you haven't another config in place.

**And note** that update_attributes consumes a hash of "field:value" pairs ({field_1_name:field_1_value, field_2_name:field_2_value}) you want to update, not a  single applied_id only.

Answer (score 0):

You line

```
@accept = Applied.where(params[:applied_id])
```

returns an ActiveRecord relation which obviously does not have a method `update_attributes`. To fetch single record, use `first` of `find` instead:

```
@accept = Applied.find(params[:applied_id])
```

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from our [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077968/undefined-method-update-attributes-in-ruby-on-rails?noredirect=1#comment57878582_35077968).

I am not sure what actually `accept` is and what actually you want to do specically, however, just as per my understanding, try to update your link href. It should look like:

```
apply_path(accept:{:accept => 1, applied_id: YOUR_APPLIED_ID})
```

Update your action as follow:

```
def update
  accept = params[:accept] # Recommendation: you should use strong parameter
  @accept = Applied.where(accept[:applied_id])
  params.permit!
  @accept.update_attributes(accept)

  render 'apply' # You don't need any condition, as you are rendering same template in every case.
end
```

Comment: Hi @RAJ `accept` means one field name into the table, I need update `1` into the `accept` field

Comment: Thanks @try.. Regrets for late response, however, I think my answer had helped you to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you're trying to update a `collection` (`where`) which does not have the `update_attributes` method available.

What you need is [`.find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find):

```
def update
  @accept = Applied.find params[:applied_id]
  @accept.update applied_params
  render 'apply'
end

private

def applied_params
  params.require(:accept).permit(:accept)
end
```

*However*, you're not passing any `applied_id` parameter (so the `find` won't work); you need to use the following route:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :applied do
   put :apply, action: :update #-> url.com/applied/:applied_id/apply
end

<%= link_to "Accept", apply_path([[[applied.id]]], accept:{:accept => 1}), :method => :put, class: "btn btn-success" %>
```

A much better way would be to use `button_to`:

```
<%= button_to "Accept", apply_path([[applied_id]]), method: :put, params: {accept: 1} %>
```

If you used the above, you'd have to change your `params` method in your controller.

--

If you wanted to use `.where` (for multiple records),  you'll need to use [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all):

```
def update
  @accept = Applied.where id: params[:applied_id]
  @accept.update_all applied_params
  render 'apply'
end

private

def applied_params
  params.require(:accept).permit(:accept)
end
```

Comment: I used your suggestion `<%= button_to "Accept", apply_path([[applied_id]]), method: :put, params: {accept: 1} %>` but showing `undefined local variable or method applied_id`. for example I have a list, I need update `1` into `accept` field for every item into list, just click `accept` ind update `1`

Comment: `[[applied_id]]` is my placeholder for where you should insert your `@applied_id`

Answer (score 0):

If you're finding this error from Rails 6 onwards, it's because `update_attributes` is deprecated, and has been replaced simply with `update` per https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/8705.

Updating the call directly resolved the issue for me.